# How do I use select with multiple like conditions in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to select all records from a table which are not `like '%select%'` but except these which contains `'%select some_string%'` and `'%select some_other_string%'`.

How do I do this in T-SQL?

Comment: I have no idea how the statement should looks like. You don't need to write whole statemant. I only need some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward translation from English to SQL should work fine:

```
WHERE (NOT (s LIKE '%select%'))
  AND NOT ((s LIKE '%select some_string%') OR (s LIKE '%select some_other_string%'))
```

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. I even don't hink that I can use De Morgan's law (used it long time ago at school). I have some other question. Is there possibility to use 'in' for strings?
eg. select * from table where text_column in ('word1', 'word2')

Comment: @user2027004 Although you can use `in` for strings, you need to supply exact values, so it wouldn't work with the `like` operator.

Answer (score 1):

With my english skills I get another solution than dasblinkenlight's:

```
WHERE (NOT (s LIKE '%select%'))
  OR s LIKE '%select some_string%' OR s LIKE '%select some_other_string%'
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No offense ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following it may help

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Coloumn NOT LIKE 'select'
    AND Coloumn LIKE '%select some_string%'
```